# TwitteR: 'searchTwitter' function only returns a very small set of tweets

Tags: api, twitter, oauth, hashtag, tweets

I am trying to fetch tweets using searchTwitter() to fetch maximum number tweets allowed to fetch by twitterR API (I believe that limit is around 3000.) But in result I'm only getting two tweets, although I can see on twitter bc when I check the hashtag on twitter (via browser or app) I see there are more than 1000 posts.
Below is the message I get.

```html
library("ROAuth")
library("bitops")
library("twitteR")
library("RCurl")
library("NLP")
library("tm")
library("RColorBrewer")
library("wordcloud")

api_key <-"xxxxx" #works out
api_secret <-"xxxxx"
accec_token <-"xxxx"
acces_token_secret<-"xxxxxx"
setup_twitter_oauth(api_key,api_secret,accec_token,acces_token_secret)

car3<- searchTwitter("#شعب_الحرمين_ضد_قياده_المراه_3", n=500 , lang="en")
jihadDf <- twListToDF(car3)
head(jihadDf)

Warning message:
In doRppAPICall("search/tweets", n, params = params, retryOnRateLimit = retryOnRateLimit,  :
  500 tweets were requested but the API can only return 2
```